# Is UUID really unique? why can we assign multiple UUIDs to single slice of disk

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, uuid

All the web content and its acronym explains it as Uniquely identifier.

But when i try to create another device, lets say swap in my case and assign the UUID, i am able to assign many UUIDs to single slice of disk.

I can create multiple swap device with different UUIDs, using command mkswap with -U option to it.

Then, how it is unique..?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Answer (score 0):

It's Unique in the sense that the same UUID should not be generated twice.  This is not exactly guaranteed, because part (sometimes all) of the generation process uses random numbers, but statistically it is unlikely that a new UUID will be in use anywhere else in the world.

Comment: GUID and UUID ...hmm,I COULD imagine, that those are unique in ONE computer, but all over the world, it is only relatively unlikely, that they can occur several times with the same value. Nevertheless there is no mechanism which guarantees this, right ?

Comment: @icbytes: you should read the many docs online about this, but it is correct to say there's no mechanism which guarantees it fully.  Without communication between the various entities generating UUIDs it's not clear how there could be any such guarantee.

Comment: I am aware that a device will be assigned a unique UUID, by unique i think its on system, its not like unique in the world.

My concern: On my setup, i can create multiple swap devices, where Veritas VxVM product is installed and used. Here, i have OS device path with one UUID AND veritas vxvm device with another UUID and both are swap devices. Doesn't this mean, we have a single physical part of disk and many logical partitions are pointing to the same part/slice of disk but having different UUIDs

Comment: If you're asking if two different logical partitions can reside on the same portion of the same physical disk: no, they cannot.  Probably the two UUIDs are basically two "names" for the very same partition.